# While installing, debian does not show my individual partitions

Tags: windows-7, linux, installation, debian

In my dual boot PC, I am trying to install Debian. This is how my disk partition looks like.

[image]

When i try to create a partition in the debian installation it shows this 250GB entirely. When i select that partition it is asking if it can remove the entire contents in the partition. I have my windows and ubuntu installed already. How to come out of this problem.

Thanks in advance,
Chidambaram